# Use multitenancy or custom solutions

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

It is not an issue but a question or advice on what is better approach given the concepts of abp. In my case there are different kind of roles that interact with some core entities. Let say.

Entities:

MedicalClaim : FullAuditedEntity

PharmacyClaim : FullAuditedEntity

Ticket : FullAuditedEntity

Roles:

Admin

Manager

Auditor

Insurer

ProfessionalBiller

PharmacyBiller

HospitalBiller

Physician (User)

The real interaction with the defined Entities is Role to Role, ex. MedicalClaim is billed by ProfessionalBiller or Physician to an Insurer. Users belong to a company or are individual physicians. Manager, Admin and Auditor are users one level up.

**MULTITENANCY = TRUE**
If using multitenancy approach how can i differentiate different kind of tenants in ABP, because every tenant is not the same kind of Customer and i need interactions between tenants. In this case Admin, Manager and Auditor will be HOST users so they can manage Tenants and entities related to tenants (Medical Claims and Tickets). How to set automatic filtering so every tenant can see "own" entities, if PharmacyBiller bill to Insurer it should be filter in both cases, first when PharmacyBiller (FROM) user enter to the system and when Insurer (TO) enter to the system. using multitenancy we get all the benefits (FEATURE, EDITIONS), so for example don't need to duplicate permissions per Roles. ex. PharmacyBiller (CAN_CREATE_CLAIM) and ProfessionalBiller (CAN_CREATE_CLAIM) and differentiate what kind of role by features ("PHARMACY_CLAIM") and ("PROFESSIONAL_CLAIM")

**MULTITENACY = FALSE**
If we don't use multitenancy we lose all the concepts related to multitenancy and a lot of duplicated code rise, but maybe we get more flexibility with custom development. An alternative here can be use OrganizationUnit, OrganizationUnitRole and permissions and treat every Role as an OrganizationUnit for filtering purpose. Here every time we create any instance of a Role internally we need to create an OrganizationUnit so the source of EntityId can be unique to avoid polluting the User entity with a lot of null per role.

I think this is a very common scenario mentioned here on aspnetboilerplate/zero, and some hints are welcome from the community or support team (know the drawbacks of some solutions even when it make sense)

Answer (score 0):

aspnet boilerplate has multitenant filtering by default, if you want to disable it you can use https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters, or check more details about the framework https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy?searchKey=multi-tenancy%20asp.net%20boilerplate

```
 var people1 = _personRepository.GetAllList ();
 using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter (AbpDataFilters.FILTER_NAME_HERE))
 {
     var people2 = _personRepository.GetAllList ();
 }
 var people3 = _personRepository.GetAllList ();
```

I recommend using multitenant